# Is inbuild use of javascript in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have heard that `HTML5` uses some sort of javascript within... Does `CSS3` also does that, I don't think the `transitions` can work otherwise..
Reason of asking, I don't want any `javascript` in my `CSS` part.. I am trying to build a pure css library like `pureio` and `bootstrap`, they both contain javascript also although..

Comment: JavaScript can be contained within HTML `<script>` elements, if that what is meant .. but there is no such similar concept in CSS.

Comment: No I meant, does css3 has inbuilt use of javascript somewhere. If any reference you have regarding this, that will be helpful.

Comment: uh, what? css is css, html is html, javascript is javascript. You can use each and every one separately, or together, or in unison, or whatever.

Comment: @Zirak HTML5 does use javascript in SSE... So I am asking, does CSS3 also use javascript in some way.. (automatically behind the curtains)

Comment: @user3901534 No, SSE is unrelated to html5. Server-Sent Events is a javascript API. CSS is implemented inside of the browser - you can even open up the source code of Chrome and Firefox to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 doesn't have any javascript within as such.

Some new elements when implemented by the browser may however have some of the HTML5 features rendered using JS or at least provide a JS API as per specification.

Like any other HTML version prior that, otherwise we wouldn't be able to bind events or control HTML elements via Javascript.

And for CSS no, of course not there is no JS dependencies. How would CSS work when JS is disabled?

And remember browsers have access to the all computer power. It wouldn't make a lot of sense to ignore that and do everything in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks... atleast something in right direction. I am a bit dazzled about this all..